# Adding pipeline trigger from separate project in azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have two projects in azure, need to trigger pipeline from pipeline in the another project. I installed the extension 'triggers azure devops pipeline' from marketplace.
Please help me with configuring this extension in the yaml file
[Please see the screenshot of my yaml file and extension]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGOJ4.png

The azure devops service connection dropdown of the 'triggers azure devops pipeline' extension is not displaying any value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot , it seems that you haven't created a `Azure Devops API` service connection.

You could navigate to `Project Settings -> Service connections` and create a `Azure Devops API` service connection.

[image]

**Note:** the Personal Access Token needs the following rights:

1.Triggering a Release: Release – Read, write & execute – Build Read & Execute

2.Triggering a Build: Build  Read & Execute

Then you could get the Azure Devops Service Connection in the target task.

[image: Result]

For more information, you could refer to [the introduction of the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i tried with this and worked